# php asset error echo else

Tags: php, loops, foreach, error-handling

I have this code on a form where users can update their details. It works but if users successfully updates once, then updates someone else which errors then the error message appear but success message doesn't disappear which is confusing.

Is there a way to use a foreach loop within the if else?

```
    <?php
                    //check for any errors
                    if(isset($error)){
                        foreach($error as $error){
                            echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$error.'</p>';
                        }
                    }

                    if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'updated'){
                        echo "<p class='bg-success'>Your details have been updated.</p>";
                    }
                    ?>
```

Comment: Using the same var name for an array and its consequent elements is confusing to read and will lead to errors (huh).  When naming an array I access it as plural, unless you use the notion of type hinting : eg foreach($errors as $error) or foreach($Aerrors as $error), ugly, but some shops work like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your $_GET['action'] is still set to updated. So two options:
1. wrap the $_GET['action'] in an else so it won't fire if there's an error,

```
//check for any errors
if(isset($error)){
    foreach($error as $error){
        echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$error.'</p>';
    }
} ELSE { // add this!
    if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'updated'){
        echo "<p class='bg-success'>Your details have been updated.</p>";
    }
}
```

OR make sure that $_GET['action'] is not set to updated when it hasn't been updated successfully

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly! I tried and tried this but must have been getting the syntax wrong